# How to draw lines (segments) using the arrow keys?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

I'm trying to resolve an excercise about drawing lines using the arrow keys. The line starts from the center and draws toward east, west, north or south when one of the arrow keys is pressed. The code works only in east or west direction and not in a north or south and that is my problem!!

Could someone give me an idea about this matter? Thanks.

Here's the code:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class DrawingLinesUsingTheArrowKeys extends JFrame {

    // Create a panel
    private LinesUsingTheArrowKeys LinesUsingTheArrowKeys = new LinesUsingTheArrowKeys();

    public DrawingLinesUsingTheArrowKeys() {

        add(LinesUsingTheArrowKeys);

        /*
         * A component (keyboard) must be focused for its can receive the
         * KeyEvent To make a component focusable , set its focusable property
         * to true
         */
        LinesUsingTheArrowKeys.setFocusable(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new DrawingLinesUsingTheArrowKeys();
        frame.setTitle("Drawing Lines Using The Arrow Keys");
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(400, 200);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    // Inner class: LinesUsingTheArrowKeys (keyboardPanel) for receiving key
    // input
    static class LinesUsingTheArrowKeys extends JPanel {
        private int x = 200;
        private int y = 100;
        private int x1 = x + 10;
        private int y1 = y;

        // register listener
        public LinesUsingTheArrowKeys() {
            addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
                @Override
                public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
                    if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN) {
                        // x1 += y1;
                        y1 += 10;

                        repaint();
                    } else if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_UP) {
                        y1 -= 10;
                        repaint();
                    } else if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT) {
                        x1 += 10;
                        repaint();
                    } else if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT) {
                        x1 -= 10;
                        repaint();
                    }

                }
            });
        }

        // Draw the line(s)
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);

            g.drawLine(x, y, x1, y1);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think before you go to much further, you may want to learn the difference between Java and JavaScript

Comment: ok...i'm so stressed out about the pbm + new in java = some errors when posting the question...but i'll look after that..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first mistake is using a `KeyListener`.  `KeyListener` will only respond to key events when the component is registered to is focusable AND has focus.

Your second mistake is not providing size hints for your `LinesUsingTheArrowKeys` class, so the layout manager has some idea of how big your component should be.

You third mistake is assuming that painting in Swing is accumative, which it is not.  Painting in Swing is destructive.  That is, each time `paintComponent` is called, the expectation is that the `Graphics` context will be cleared and what ever needs to be painted will be completely regenerated.

Take a look at:

- [How to use Key Bindings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html)
- [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/)
- [2D Graphics](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/)
- [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html)...because every body that wants to do painting in Swing should know how this works

Basically, a better solution would be to have a `List` of `Point`, which the `paintComponent` would simply either generate a `Line` between them or even maybe some kind of `Polygon` or `Shape`.  You would then simply add a new `Point` to this `List` as you require and then repaint the component

Comment: thanks for that. Is it possible to show me just a hint how to create a list of point?

Comment: Try taking a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14088470/java-challenge-on-permitting-the-user-to-draw-a-line/14088561#14088561) (it's at the end of the answer), [another possibility](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15396258/drawpolygon-keeps-drawing-lines-from-starting-mousepressed-location-to-current/15398270#15398270)