# Drawing in a Paint Method - Java

Tags: java

I am only posting the relevant code. I am fairly new to java and right now I am building a program that will allow the user to use a draw method. However, when I click the button for drawing in the interface, it automatically generates a random line anywhere on the page and does not allow user interaction. I think the error is occurring in my mouseListener method, but I am not sure as this is my first time doing anything like this. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Also, the error that prints out is: Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException

```
public class SimplePaint extends JFrame {

    JButton drawing = new JButton();
    Line2D draw = new Line2D.Float();
    Point start = null;
    Point end = null;

public SimplePaint() {
    JPanel panel = new JPanel() {  
      {
          addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
              public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
                  start = e.getPoint();  
              }

              public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
                  start = e.getPoint();
                  //start = null;
              }
          });
          addMouseMotionListener(new MouseMotionAdapter() {
              public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {
                  end = e.getPoint();
              }

              public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
                  end = e.getPoint();
                  repaint();
              }
          });
      }
  };

drawing.setText("Draw");
panel.add(drawing);

ActionListener actionListener = new ActionListener() {     
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if (e.getSource() == drawing) {
        draw = new Line2D.Float(start.x, start.y, end.x, end.y);
        }
        repaint();
    }
};

drawing.addActionListener(actionListener);

}

public void paint(Graphics g) {
    super.paint(g);
    Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
    Line2D line = new Line2D.Float(0, 250, 2000, 300);
    g2.draw(draw);
}
}
```

Comment: You are calling the repaint for the JPanel and the Paint method is in the JFrame, try adding the Listeners to the JFrame

Comment: Could you please [edit] your question and post the error and stacktrace?

Comment: I have tried moving the method and I am still getting the same error. The reference that prints out is Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException. Thank you!

Comment: Explain more what you want. _However, when I click the button for drawing in the interface, it automatically generates a random line anywhere on the page and does not allow user interaction._... this is not enough. Do you want do draw a line with your mouse and make it clickable?

Comment: I want to draw a line with my mouse. I have another method that will erase.

Comment: Did you read this post: [java draw line as the mouse is moved](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9711938/java-draw-line-as-the-mouse-is-moved)?

Comment: Yes, that is actually what I followed when writing my code, and I just tweaked it to match my logic.

Comment: And read this afterwards: [Java Swing draw lines with mouse click and drag](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40253767/java-swing-draw-lines-with-mouse-click-and-drag)

Comment: I have followed both of these posts, this is where I got my logic from. This is my first time writing anything like this. If you have any suggestion on what is wrong with my logic, that would be great. :)

Comment: Take a closer look. `paint` belongs to your panel and use `paintComponent` instead. You also forgot to add panel to your frame.

Comment: Here is good page for drawing. [Example 3: Paint](http://www.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/java/J4b_CustomGraphics.html#mypaint)

Comment: Would you mind posting an answer so I can get a better understanding?