# Java drawing on sceen using mouse not working

Tags: java, swing, drawing, screen, graphics2d

I am trying to make a Digital Doily application using Swing and Graphics2D. I have never before used either Swing or done any 2d graphics. When you hold the mouse you should be able to draw stuff, but for some reason it is not working and I can't figure out why. I am not posting the GalleryPanel.java class, because it doesn't affect in any way the drawing. Here is my code:

Main.java

```
    public class Main {

    public static final int WINDOW_WIDTH = 1600;
    public static final int WINDOW_HEIGHT = 800;
    public static final int SIDE_MENU_WIDTH = WINDOW_WIDTH / 4;
    public static final String TITLE = "Digital Doily";
    public static final Font PANEL_TITLE_FONT = new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 16);

    /**
     * Just a main method used to run the JFrame window
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        WindowFrame frame = new WindowFrame(WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT, TITLE);
    }
}
```

WindowFrame.java

```
    public class WindowFrame extends JFrame {

    /**
     * The width of the window
     */
    private int width;

    /**
     * The height of the window
     */
    private int height;

    /**
     * The main constructor of the window
     * @param width - width of the window
     * @param height - height of the window
     * @param title - title of the window
     */
    public WindowFrame(int width, int height, String title) {
        super(title);
        this.setSize(new Dimension(width, height));
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.setFont(new Font("Times New Roman", Font.PLAIN, 12));

        // Initializing the main GUI elements
        initializeGUI();

        this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        this.setVisible(true);
    }

    /**
     * The main GUI of the window frame
     */
    private void initializeGUI() {
        JPanel window = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        this.setContentPane(window);

        //Doily panel
        DoilyPanel doilyPanel = new DoilyPanel();
        doilyPanel.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        window.add(doilyPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        // Gallery panel
        GalleryPanel galleryPanel = new GalleryPanel(doilyPanel);
        galleryPanel.setBackground(Color.getColor("DDDDDD"));
        window.add(galleryPanel, BorderLayout.EAST);

        // Options panel
        OptionsPanel optionPanel = new OptionsPanel(this, doilyPanel, galleryPanel);
        optionPanel.setBackground(Color.getColor("DDDDDD"));
        window.add(optionPanel, BorderLayout.WEST);

        window.setVisible(true);

    }
}
```

OptionsPanel.java

```
    public class OptionsPanel extends JPanel {

    /**
     * An instance of the DoilyPanel class
     */
    private DoilyPanel doilyPanel;

    /**
     * An instance of JFrame
     */
    private JFrame frame;
    private GalleryPanel galleryPanel;

    public OptionsPanel(JFrame frame, DoilyPanel doilyPanel, GalleryPanel galleryPanel) {
        this.doilyPanel = doilyPanel;
        this.frame = frame;
        this.galleryPanel = galleryPanel;

        /**
         * Start of GUI
         */
        this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(Main.SIDE_MENU_WIDTH, Main.WINDOW_HEIGHT));
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        //Initializing the panel GUI elements
        initializeGUI();

        setVisible(true);

        /**
         * End of GUI
         */
    }

    /**
     * The main GUI of the panel
     */
    private void initializeGUI() {
        // Title panel
        JPanel titlePanel = new JPanel();
        titlePanel.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        this.add(titlePanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);

        // Options title label
        JLabel optionsTitle = new JLabel("Options");
        optionsTitle.setFont(Main.PANEL_TITLE_FONT);
        titlePanel.add(optionsTitle);

        titlePanel.setVisible(true);

        // Main panel
        JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER,10,10));
        mainPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(Main.SIDE_MENU_WIDTH, Main.WINDOW_WIDTH - titlePanel.getHeight()));
        this.add(mainPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        // Doily sector
        JLabel sectorTitle = new JLabel("Sectors: ");
        mainPanel.add(sectorTitle);

        SpinnerModel sectorSpinnerModel = new SpinnerNumberModel(doilyPanel.getSectors(), 1,100,1);
        JSpinner sectorSpinner = new JSpinner(sectorSpinnerModel);
        mainPanel.add(sectorSpinner);

        // Pen size
        JLabel penSizeTitle = new JLabel("Pen size: ");
        mainPanel.add(penSizeTitle);

        SpinnerModel penSizeSpinnerModel = new SpinnerNumberModel(doilyPanel.getPenSize(), 1,100,1);
        JSpinner penSizeSpinner = new JSpinner(penSizeSpinnerModel);
        mainPanel.add(penSizeSpinner);

        // Clear
        JButton clearButton = new JButton("Clear");
        mainPanel.add(clearButton);

        // Undo
        JButton undoButton = new JButton("Undo");
        mainPanel.add(undoButton);

        // Redo
        JButton redoButton = new JButton("Redo");
        mainPanel.add(redoButton);

        // Delete
        JButton deleteButton = new JButton("Delete");
        mainPanel.add(deleteButton);

        // Change pen color
        JButton changePenColorButton = new JButton("Change pen color");
        mainPanel.add(changePenColorButton);

        // Save
        JButton saveButton = new JButton("Save");
        mainPanel.add(saveButton);

        // Toggle sector lines
        JButton toggleSectorLinesButton = new JButton("Sector lines: " + doilyPanel.getSectorLinesStatus());
        mainPanel.add(toggleSectorLinesButton);

        // Toggle reflections
        JButton toggleReflectionButton = new JButton("Reflections: " + doilyPanel.getReflectedDrawingStatus());
        mainPanel.add(toggleReflectionButton);

        // Toggle eraser
        JButton toggleEraserButton = new JButton("Eraser: ");
        mainPanel.add(toggleEraserButton);

        // Creating a new OptionsPanelListener
        OptionsPanelListener optionsPanelListener = new OptionsPanelListener(
                frame, doilyPanel, galleryPanel, penSizeSpinner, sectorSpinner, clearButton, undoButton, redoButton, deleteButton,
                changePenColorButton, saveButton, toggleSectorLinesButton, toggleReflectionButton, toggleEraserButton
        );

        // Adding all listeners to the components
        sectorSpinner.addChangeListener(optionsPanelListener);

        mainPanel.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

OptionsPanelListener.java

```
public class OptionsPanelListener implements ActionListener, ChangeListener {

    private JFrame frame;
    private DoilyPanel doilyPanel;
    private GalleryPanel galleryPanel;
    private JSpinner sectorSpinner;
    private JSpinner penSizeSpinner;
    private JButton clearButton;
    private JButton undoButton;
    private JButton redoButton;
    private JButton deleteButton;
    private JButton changePenColorButton;
    private JButton saveButton;
    private JButton toggleSectorLinesButton;
    private JButton toggleReflectionButton;
    private JButton toggleEraserButton;

    public OptionsPanelListener(
            JFrame frame, DoilyPanel doilyPanel, GalleryPanel galleryPanel, JSpinner penSizeSpinner, JSpinner sectorSpinner, JButton clearButton, JButton undoButton, JButton redoButton,
            JButton deleteButton, JButton changePenColorButton, JButton saveButton, JButton toggleSectorLinesButton, JButton toggleReflectionButton, JButton toggleEraserButton
    ) {
        this.frame = frame;
        this.doilyPanel = doilyPanel;
        this.galleryPanel = galleryPanel;
        this.penSizeSpinner = penSizeSpinner;
        this.sectorSpinner = sectorSpinner;
        this.clearButton = clearButton;
        this.undoButton = undoButton;
        this.redoButton = redoButton;
        this.deleteButton = deleteButton;
        this.changePenColorButton = changePenColorButton;
        this.saveButton = saveButton;
        this.toggleSectorLinesButton = toggleSectorLinesButton;
        this.toggleReflectionButton = toggleReflectionButton;
        this.toggleEraserButton = toggleEraserButton;
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if (e.getSource() == clearButton) {
            doilyPanel.removeStrokes();
            doilyPanel.repaint();
        } else if(e.getSource() == undoButton) {
            if (!doilyPanel.getStrokes().isEmpty()) {
                doilyPanel.removeStrokes(doilyPanel.getStrokesSize());
                doilyPanel.repaint();
            }
            // TO DO:
        } else if (e.getSource() == redoButton) {
            if (!doilyPanel.getStrokes().isEmpty()) {
                doilyPanel.repaint();
            }
        } else if (e.getSource() == changePenColorButton) {
            Color color = JColorChooser.showDialog(frame, "Change pen color", frame.getBackground());
            if (color != null) {
                doilyPanel.setStrokeColor(color);
                doilyPanel.setColor(color);
            }
            doilyPanel.repaint();
        } else if(e.getSource() == saveButton) {
            if (galleryPanel.getDoilies().size() < 12) {
                BufferedImage doily = DoilyPanel.resizeDoily(doilyPanel.saveDoily(doilyPanel), 100, 100);
                galleryPanel.addDoily(new JLabel(new ImageIcon(doily)));
                galleryPanel.revalidate();
            } else {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The maximum number of doilies you can save is 12.");
            }
        } else if (e.getSource() == toggleSectorLinesButton) {
            doilyPanel.toggleSectorLines();
            doilyPanel.setSectorLinesStatus(doilyPanel.updateSectorLinesStatus());
            doilyPanel.repaint();
        } else if(e.getSource() == toggleReflectionButton) {
            doilyPanel.toggleReflectDrawing();
            doilyPanel.setReflectedDrawingStatus(doilyPanel.updateReflectDrawingStatus());
            doilyPanel.repaint();
        } else if (e.getSource() == toggleEraserButton) {

        }
    }

    @Override
    public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e) {
        if (e.getSource() == penSizeSpinner) {
            doilyPanel.setPenSize((int)penSizeSpinner.getValue());
            doilyPanel.setStrokePenSize((int) penSizeSpinner.getValue());
            doilyPanel.repaint();

            //doilyPanel.repaint();
        } else if (e.getSource() == sectorSpinner) {
            doilyPanel.setSectors((int) sectorSpinner.getValue());
            doilyPanel.setSectorsAngle(360.0 / doilyPanel.getSectors());
            doilyPanel.repaint();
        }
    }
}
```

DoilyPanel.java

```
public class DoilyPanel extends JPanel {

    /**
     * How many sectors the doily has
     */
    private int sectors;

    /**
     * The angle between each sector line
     */
    private double sectorsAngle;

    /**
     * How big the size of the pen is
     */
    private int penSize;

    /**
     * The color of the pen
     */
    private Color color = Color.WHITE;

    /**
     * Whether sector lines are activated
     */
    private boolean sectorLines = true;

    private String sectorLinesStatus;

    /**
     * Whether reflected drawing is activated
     */
    private boolean reflectedDrawing = false;

    private String reflectedDrawingStatus;

    /**
     * The drawing area of the doily
     */
    private BufferedImage canvas;

    private Pen stroke;

    private ArrayList<Pen> strokes;

    /**
     * |---------------------------------- Methods ----------------------------------|
     */

    /**
     * Get method for sectors property
     * @return the number of sectors
     */
    public int getSectors() {
        return sectors;

    }

    /**
     * Set method for sectors property
     * @param sectors - new number of sectors
     */
    public void setSectors(int sectors) {
        this.sectors = sectors;
    }

    public void setSectorsAngle(double sectorsAngle) {
        this.sectorsAngle = sectorsAngle;
    }

    public double getSectorsAngle() {
        return sectorsAngle;
    }

    /**
     * Get method for
     * @return
     */
    public int getPenSize() {
        return penSize;
    }

    public void setPenSize(int penSize) {
        this.penSize = penSize;
    }

    public Pen getStroke() {
        return stroke;
    }

    public void setStroke(Pen stroke) {
        this.stroke = stroke;
    }

    public void setStrokeColor(Color color) {
        this.stroke.setColor(color);
    }

    public void setStrokePenSize(int size) {
        this.stroke.setSize(size);
    }

    public void setColor(Color color) {
        this.color = color;
    }

    public Color getColor() {
        return color;
    }

    public void setCanvas(BufferedImage canvas) {
        this.canvas = canvas;
    }

    public BufferedImage getCanvas() {
        return canvas;
    }

    public boolean getSectorLines() {
        return sectorLines;
    }

    public String getSectorLinesStatus() {
        return sectorLinesStatus;
    }

    public void setSectorLinesStatus(String sectorLinesStatus) {
        this.sectorLinesStatus = sectorLinesStatus;
    }

    public boolean getReflectDrawing() {
        return reflectedDrawing;
    }

    public String getReflectedDrawingStatus() {
        return reflectedDrawingStatus;
    }

    public void setReflectedDrawingStatus(String reflectedDrawingStatus) {
        this.reflectedDrawingStatus = reflectedDrawingStatus;
    }

    public void addPoint(MouseEvent event) {
        if (!(sectors % 2 == 0)) {
            stroke.addPoint(new Point(event.getY() - this.getWidth() / 2, event.getX() - this.getWidth() / 2));
        } else {
            stroke.addPoint(new Point(event.getY() - this.getWidth() / 2, -event.getX() - this.getWidth() / 2));
        }
        repaint();
    }

    public ArrayList<Pen> getStrokes() {
        return strokes;
    }

    public int getStrokesSize() {
        return strokes.size() - 1;
    }

    public void removeStrokes(int index) {
        this.strokes.remove(index);
    }

    public void removeStrokes() {
        this.strokes.clear();
    }

    public String updateSectorLinesStatus() {
        if (sectorLines) {
            return "On";
        }
        return "Off";
    }

    public String updateReflectDrawingStatus() {
        if (reflectedDrawing) {
            return "On";
        }
        return "Off";
    }

    public DoilyPanel() {
        setSectors(6);
        setSectorsAngle(360.0 / getSectors());
        setPenSize(2);
        setColor(Color.BLUE);
        stroke = new Pen(this);
        strokes = new ArrayList<>();
        canvas = new BufferedImage(800, 800, BufferedImage.TYPE_4BYTE_ABGR);
        setSectorLinesStatus(updateSectorLinesStatus());
        setReflectedDrawingStatus(updateReflectDrawingStatus());
        this.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        this.addMouseListener(new DoilyPanelListener(this));
        this.addMouseMotionListener(new DoilyPanelListener(this));
    }

    public void toggleSectorLines() {
        sectorLines = !sectorLines;
    }

    public void toggleReflectDrawing() {
        reflectedDrawing = !reflectedDrawing;
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);

        Graphics2D graphics2D = (Graphics2D) g;

        graphics2D.setColor(Color.BLACK);

        // Centering the image
        graphics2D.translate(this.getWidth() / 2, this.getHeight() / 2);

        if (sectorLines) {
            for (int i = 0; i < sectors; i++) {
                graphics2D.setColor(Color.WHITE);
                graphics2D.setStroke(new BasicStroke(1));
                graphics2D.drawLine(0, 0, 0, 364);
                graphics2D.rotate(Math.toRadians(sectorsAngle));
            }
        }

        graphics2D.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        graphics2D.setStroke(new BasicStroke(penSize));


        for (int i = 0; i < strokes.size(); i++) {
            strokes.get(i).paint(graphics2D);
        }
        stroke.paint(graphics2D);

    }

    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        super.paint(g);
    }

    public static BufferedImage resizeDoily(BufferedImage doily, int width, int height) {
        BufferedImage resized = new BufferedImage(width, height, BufferedImage.TRANSLUCENT);
        Graphics2D g2d = resized.createGraphics();
        g2d.addRenderingHints(new RenderingHints(RenderingHints.KEY_RENDERING, RenderingHints.VALUE_RENDER_QUALITY));
        g2d.drawImage(doily, 0, 0, width, height, null);
        g2d.dispose();
        return resized;
    }

    public BufferedImage saveDoily(JPanel panel) {
        BufferedImage doily = new BufferedImage(panel.getWidth(), panel.getHeight(), BufferedImage.TYPE_4BYTE_ABGR);
        panel.paint(doily.getGraphics());
        return  doily;
    }
}
```

DoilyPanelListener.java

```
public class DoilyPanelListener implements MouseListener, MouseMotionListener {

    private DoilyPanel doilyPanel;

    public DoilyPanelListener(DoilyPanel doilyPanel) {
        this.doilyPanel = doilyPanel;
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
        doilyPanel.addPoint(e);
    }

    @Override
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {

    }

    @Override
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
        doilyPanel.getStrokes().add(doilyPanel.getStroke());
        doilyPanel.setStroke(new Pen(doilyPanel));
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {

    }

    @Override
    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {

    }

    @Override
    public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
        doilyPanel.addPoint(e);
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {

    }
}
```

Pen.java

```
public class Pen {
    private DoilyPanel doilyPanel;
    private int size;
    private Color color;
    private boolean isReflectedOn;
    private ArrayList<Point> points;

    public void setSize(int size) {
        this.size = size;
    }

    public int getSize() {
        return size;
    }

    public void setColor(Color color) {
        this.color = color;
    }

    public Color getColor() {
        return color;
    }

    public void setReflectedOn(boolean reflectedOn) {
        isReflectedOn = reflectedOn;
    }

    public void setPoints(ArrayList<Point> points) {
        this.points = points;
    }

    public ArrayList<Point> getPoints() {
        return points;
    }

    public Pen(DoilyPanel doilyPanel) {
        this.doilyPanel = doilyPanel;
        setSize(doilyPanel.getPenSize());
        setColor(doilyPanel.getColor());
        setReflectedOn(doilyPanel.getReflectDrawing());
        points = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public void addPoint(Point p) {
        this.points.add(p);
    }

    public void paint(Graphics graphics) {
        Graphics2D graphics2D = (Graphics2D) graphics;

        graphics2D.setColor(color);

        for (int i = 0; i < doilyPanel.getSectors(); i++) {
            graphics2D.setStroke(new BasicStroke(size));
            Point point1 = null;
            if (points.size() == 1) {
                point1 = points.get(0);
                graphics2D.drawRect((int)point1.getX(), (int)point1.getY(), doilyPanel.getPenSize(), doilyPanel.getPenSize());

                // Draw Reflections if they are on
                if (isReflectedOn) {
                    graphics2D.drawRect(-(int)point1.getX(), (int)point1.getY(), doilyPanel.getPenSize(), doilyPanel.getPenSize());
                }
                graphics2D.rotate(Math.toRadians(doilyPanel.getSectorsAngle()));
            } else if (points.size() > 1){
                Iterator<Point> pointsIterator = points.iterator();
                point1 = pointsIterator.next();

                while (pointsIterator.hasNext()) {
                    Point point2 = pointsIterator.next();
                    graphics2D.drawRect((int)point1.getX(), (int)point1.getY(), (int)point2.getX(), (int)point2.getY());

                    // Draw Reflections if they are on
                    if (isReflectedOn) {
                        graphics2D.drawLine(-(int)point1.getX(), (int)point1.getY(), -(int)point2.getX(), (int)point2.getY());
                    }

                    point1 = point2;
                }
                graphics2D.rotate(Math.toRadians(doilyPanel.getSectorsAngle()));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: For better help sooner post a [mcve] (not code snippets / your whole code), as is, there's a lot of code here...

Comment: [Related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40253767/java-swing-draw-lines-with-mouse-click-and-drag) and this other [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9711938/java-draw-line-as-the-mouse-is-moved)

Comment: Thanks, I will look into it. Sorry for the long code. I felt like most of the things were necessary, because it's a mini app and somebody might wonder where all those things are coming from.

Comment: Read the link I provided, you need to create a new project which only tries to draw a line when dragging the mouse, no need for the spinners, or the `JButton`s, etc...